# Remove phrase and parenthesis and sort the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

## Given a sample data frame:

```
df = 

                               multi
0 MULTIPOLYGON(((1.1 1.2, 2.1 2.2)))
1 MULTIPOLYGON(((3.1 3.2, 4.1 4.2)))
2 MULTIPOLYGON(((5.1 5.2, 6.1 6.1)))
```

## Disred output:

```
df = 

 a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2 a_3 b_3
 1.1 1.2 3.1 3.2 5.1 5.2
 2.1 2.2 4.1 4.2 6.1 6.2
```

---

I did very long process, which is very bad even to put here.

1. Step one:

Delete `MULTIPOLYGON`, then `(((`, then `)))`

2. Step two:

Split on comma

3. Step three:

Transpose and then split on space

I am sure there should be nicer, wiser way to do that (it is easy to do on excel, but I need to do with python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `str.extract`, `str.split`, `transform` and `pd.concat`:

We can do this in multiple steps:

1. First we extract the numbers between `((( ... )))`
2. Then we split on `,` and `transform` the rows to columns
3. We split each two numbers on whitespace and `concat` the new data side by side

```
temp = df['multi'].str.extract('\(\(\((.*)\)\)\)')[0].str.split(',', expand=True).T

df_new = pd.concat(
    [temp[col].str.strip().str.split(' ', expand=True)\
     .rename(columns={0:f'a_{n+1}', 1:f'b_{n+1}'}) 
     for n, col in enumerate(temp.columns)], axis=1
)
```

**Output**

```
   a_1  b_1  a_2  b_2  a_3  b_3
0  1.1  1.2  3.1  3.2  5.1  5.2
1  2.1  2.2  4.1  4.2  6.1  6.2
```

---

**More explanation:**

The `list comprehension` can look quite complex, so written as a normal `for loop`, it is:

```
newdata = []
for n, col in enumerate(temp.columns):
    dftemp = temp[col].str.strip().str.split(' ', expand=True)
    dftemp = dftemp.rename(columns={0:f'a_{n+1}', 1:f'b_{n+1}'}) 

    newdata.append(dftemp)

newdf = pd.concat(newdata, axis=1)
```